# update values in numericInput R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app wherein users can input numeric values for certain fields (using `numericInput()`). Alternatively, they can choose to select values from a reference table (via a `checkboxInput()` field).

I'm able to code this behaviour in the script properly. But I also want that if the `checkboxInput` field is selected, the values displayed in the `numericInput()` get updated i.e. the default values or previously written values are overwritten.

[image]

In the screenshot, the  `numericInput` fields are highlighted in yellow. The top field has a default value of 14 whereas the others are empty. I want that the if the "Copy reference values?" `checkboxInput` is selected, the copied values get displayed in the corresponding fields (k1 = 72.49 for "Flow Coef. for dP" etc.)

My code is as below:

```
fluidRow(
    column(4,
           numericInput(inputId = "Area", 
                        label = tags$div(HTML(paste("rea (m", tags$sup(2), ")", sep = ""))),
                        min = 1, max = 100, step = 0.1, value = 14),
           numericInput(inputId = "k1", label = "Flow coef. for dP", min = 1.0, max = 600.0, value = ""),
           numericInput(inputId = "k2", label = "Flow exponent for dP" , min = 1.0, max = 20.0, value = "")
           checkboxInput("copyVals", "Copy Reference Values?", value = FALSE)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use an `observeEvent` and `updateNumericInput`s. Since you didn't provide a reproducible example here is a mockup:

```
library("shiny")
library("DT")

data <- data.frame(area = 18.61, k1 = 74.29, k2 = 1.44)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # assuming your data is reactive, not static
  data_reac <- reactive({
    data
  })

  output$parm_tab <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(data_reac())
  })

  # set the values if checked
  observeEvent(input$copyVals == TRUE, {
    c_data <- data_reac()

    updateNumericInput(session, "area", value = c_data$area)
    updateNumericInput(session, "k1", value = c_data$k1)
    updateNumericInput(session, "k2", value = c_data$k2)
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(inputId = "area", label = "Area", min = 1, max = 100, step = 0.1, value = 14),
      numericInput(inputId = "k1", label = "Flow coef. for dP", min = 1.0, max = 600.0, value = ""),
      numericInput(inputId = "k2", label = "Flow exponent for dP" , min = 1.0, max = 20.0, value = ""),
      checkboxInput("copyVals", "Copy Reference Values?", value = FALSE)
  )
  , mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("parm_tab")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]